# how should I do to solve NameError on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nameerror

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:268:in `const_get': uninitialized constant User (NameError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:268:in `block in constantize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `inject'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `constantize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/devise-4.3.0/lib/devise.rb:313:in `get'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/devise-4.3.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:81:in `to'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/devise-4.3.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:76:in `modules'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/devise-4.3.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:93:in `routes'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/devise-4.3.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:160:in `default_used_route'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/devise-4.3.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:70:in `initialize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/devise-4.3.0/lib/devise.rb:343:in `new'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/devise-4.3.0/lib/devise.rb:343:in `add_mapping'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/devise-4.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:241:in `block in devise_for'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/devise-4.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:240:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/devise-4.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:240:in `devise_for'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:389:in `instance_exec'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:389:in `eval_block'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:371:in `draw'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:77:in `execute'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:119:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:in `new'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:59:in `app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:124:in `log_to_stdout'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:77:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:9:in `require'
        from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'


Process exited with code: 1
```

Comment: models are named such as conversation.rb message.rb user.rb

Answer (score 0):

You might need to run:

```
rails generate devise User
```

According to [Devise documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started) the generator will create a model (if one does not exist) and configure it with the default Devise modules.